# UNIX Datetime format

Tags: unix

I have a scenario where there is a unix time format `2014-01-09-03-26-09_5403`.

I want to know what time format is this. When I am trying the below format:

```
start_time=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
```

It is giving me only `2014-01-09-03-26-09`.

Can you please help me in achieving this time format?

Comment: Where is it coming from? The last part has too many digits to be milliseconds.

Comment: I check `man date` and cannot find out where `5403` comes from. Could `54` be number of week since 1/1/2013? `03` would be `%d` again.

Comment: I am running one job and after the job ran successfully one logfile is getting created. so the logfile name is in 'a_2014-01-09-03-26-09_5403.log' format So i want to read this file run time. therefore i want this format in UNIX.

Comment: you should check the script/program, which generates the log, here everybody can **guess** what the four digits are, but nobody can guarantee you.

Comment: The date format is genrated by system and getting added in the filename automatically.

Comment: How? Post the shell script part which is doing it.

Comment: Maybe the part after the underscore isn't part of the timestamp.  It could be a PID of the log file creating process or similar.